# Who claimed that "and planned that which they were not to attain" (9:74) refers to abu Sufyan and his son Mu'awiyah?

Tags: tafseer, history, reference-request, sahaba, seerah

Allah () said in surat at-Tawba:

> They swear by Allah that they did not say [anything against the Prophet] while they had said the word of disbelief and disbelieved after their [pretense of] Islam **and planned that which they were not to attain**. And they were not resentful except [for the fact] that Allah and His Messenger had enriched them of His bounty. So if they repent, it is better for them; but if they turn away, Allah will punish them with a painful punishment in this world and the Hereafter. And there will not be for them on earth any protector or helper. ([9:74](http://legacy.quran.com/9/74))

This verse seems to address the hypocrites and disbelievers. But lately I've read [an article](http://almaliky.org/subject.php?id=1001) pretending that this refers to abu Sufyan and his son Mo'awyah (and 14 others) who tried to kill the Prophet () during the [battle of Tabuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_to_Tabouk) during a march. The tafsirs I've consulted so far are quoting different interpretations on the bolded part of the text, some indeed say that somebody tried to kill the Prophet, but present other names.

My question is there any reliable authentic source which supports this claim?

Comment: I have not come across this view except by Shia sources (like the article you linked to by Al-Maliki).

Comment: @III-AK-III I know al-Maliki is considered as a quranist and some say he is close to shi'ism.